# CLion / CMake Multiple include directories issue

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm trying to build multiple executable with some source in common.
My source tree looks like this :

```
root
 - CMakeLists.txt
 - 00 - common
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - include
     - Window.h
   - sources
     - Window.cpp
 - 01 - sample
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - include
   - sources
... and so on
```

In my root CMakeLists.txt I do add_subdirectory to include common and all the samples, the common part is built as a static library.

The compilation works fine in command line and also on CLion. The problem is that CLion don't understand the structure, when I include Window.h inside Window.cpp of the "common" folder, CLion don't know it, but it offer to use "../include/Window.h" using the auto-completion.

[image]

In the CMakeLists.txt of "common" folder I do:

```
add_library(common STATIC ${sources})
target_include_directories(common PUBLIC "include")
```

I also tried to use the standard method with **include_directories()** without success.

What I did wrong ?

Comment: "*when I include let's say, Window.h in Window.cpp inside common folder*"...what do you mean? Do you mean `#include Window.h`? Which file are you including that in? Please provide a more clear description of the problem, and desired behavior. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Yes exactly, I edited the question with a screen shot and edited folder tree.
It looks like the function target_include_directories of cmake don't affect CLion, it looks like it's ignored.
I'll try to do a reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after trying to reproduce the problem, I figured out that the folder name accept space but not dashes

Removed the dashes from folder names fixed the problem